# Access another process's mount namespace

Tags: linux, mount, namespaces

Is there a way to inspect the files and directories of another mount namespace?

[setns(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html) syscall appears to be able to move a thread to another namespace, but if this functionality is not already built in to a program (a shell, fileserver, ..), it appears that executing a new process is required. And since the target mount namespace may not contain the required binary, this is a problem.

**Edit:**
What I am looking for is a "user-friendly" way to access the files in the namespace. I can imagine there being, for example, a way to mount the namespace somewhere on the host system. But since I don't know what's possible, I'm asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to define "user friendly" if you want a guaranteed satisfactory answer, but depending on your needs, `/proc/<PID>/root` to get the entire filesystem hierarchy as seen by a specific process, and `/proc/<PID>/mounts` (and `/proc/<PID>/mountinfo`) for what's mounted where, might get you where you need to go.  If you *only* have a file descriptor for a namespace, you're in a far less pleasant position, because I'm not aware of any way you can go from file descriptor to a PID that's already in the namespace, but if that's where you're coming from, you left the "user friendly" reservation a *long* time ago, and contortions are to be expected.

Comment: That `/proc/<PID>/root/` was the exact thing I was looking for, thank you! ❤️

Comment: The `/proc/<PID>/root/` is what I needed as well.  I also want to mention that I initially thought it would not work, since it appears to just be a broken symlink.  But if you actually try to access it, it works!